# white pupae and larvae

Tags: identification, pest-control, insects

[image]

Hi, I have just been in my garden planting some plants and I found these. I don't know if the larvae are the same as the pupae? The larvae are about 16mm long and the pupae about 10mm. The soil was quite damp but not wet as it was close to a pond. They were all about 7 to 10 cm below the surface.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Sorry I am in North Yorkshire -UK

Comment: Just based on your picture I am seeing LARVAE stage is the little white grubs.  The Pupa stage could be the other.  Someone may know if these two are even related.  Look up incomplete metamorphosis and complete metamorphosis if you are interested.  I find this entomology stuff ENTRANCING.  Here is one I was just reading on your topic.  If I come back I would love to be an entomologist/photographer, grins.  Unbelievable the life in this world so few of us get to know.  Dunno what insect this one of our team will know  will!http://animals.mom.me/difference-larva-pupa-5624.html

Comment: I don't know what these are, but I've found lots of them this spring buried in the compost, while planting out stuff from pots that have spent the winter on my patio. Never noticed them before, I'm in Kent.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably from a beetle, the gray ones are actually the larvae and the white ones the pupae. Beetles are the largest group ([order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle)) in the animal kingdom, and with largest I mean most animal species on Earth belong to the beetle order (I remember that from zoology class at University). So it is hard to exactly tell you which species this is.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the larvae of one of the water beetles, possibly Dytiscus marginalis - they like water, but do spend time outside for various reasons, and prefer to do that near the water, preferably in damp soil. They're nothing for you to worry about in terms of your plants. Information and image of larvae (scroll down) here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_diving_beetle

Comment: Hi bamboo, thanks for your id. I think you are right, but im going to keep them in a bucket of soil and will wait to confirm